# How do I use get_query_var for multiple urls when including template in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, action

I'm using below function to redirect a specific url to a specific php script file:

```
add_action('wp', function() {
if ( trim(parse_url(add_query_arg(array()), PHP_URL_PATH), '/') === 'pagename' ) {
include(locate_template('give_some.php'));
exit();
}});
```

it works only for the specified url and i want to make it work for multiple urls. Suppose a file urls.txt contain numbers of url and for which above code have to be triggered. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m a long-time WordPress developer, and one of the best responses to a WordPress problem is “that’s not a WordPress problem, just simple PHP (or JavaScript)” one. That’s a really good thing because it makes it really easy to talk about.

Your problem, as I understand it, is that you want to compare the current URL to a “file” of possible paths. You’ve got the WordPress equivalent of “current URL”, so I’ll take that for granted, and I’ll also assume you can take a file and convert it into an array. But once you do that, you are parsing a URL (which you already did) and seeing if it is in the array:

```php
$url = 'https://www.example.com/pagename?a=b&c=d';

$paths = [
    'gerp',
    'pagename',
    'cheese',
];


$path = trim(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), '/');
if ( in_array($path, $paths )) {
    echo 'yes';
} else {
    echo 'no';
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/NOmpk

Comment: Damn worked! Takes time to understand but at the end got the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different hook `request`. Which allow you to manipulate request.

```
add_filter( 'request', function( $request ){});
```

My simple example ( not tested ).

```
add_filter( 'request', function( $request ){
        $data = file_get_contents("database.txt"); //read the file
        $rows = explode("\n", $data); //create array separate by new line
        $rows = array_map("trim", $rows); // for removing any unwanted space
        $rowCount = count($rows); // Count your database rows

        for ($i=0; $i < $rows ; $i++) {
            if( isset( $request['pagename'] ) && $rows[$i] == $request['pagename'] ){
              include(locate_template('give_some.php'));
            }
        }

    return $request;
});
```

My advice, don't use .txt files, save your data into database, and then use it, or create `wp_option` field, and manage from Settings page.

Comment: tried but after executing above coded even the site doesn't load.